# How to concatenate a list of wav files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, audio, wav

I have a list of wav files in file.txt

```
1.wav
2.wav
...
```

I used the below command to perform the action.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file.txt -c copy output.wav
```

However I get

```
[concat @ 0x5574a8046900] Line 1: unknown keyword 1.wav: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on this wiki page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate), you need to modify your *file.txt* as follows:

```
file '1.wav'
file '2.wav'
# ... etc
```

The command itself, should work fine.

Excerpts from the page:

> ...
> This demuxer reads a list of files and other directives from a text file and demuxes them one after the other, as if all their packets had been muxed together.
> ...
>
> #### Instructions
>
> Create a file mylist.txt with all the files you want to have concatenated in the following form (lines starting with a # are ignored):
>
> ```
> # this is a comment
> file '/path/to/file1.wav'
> file '/path/to/file2.wav'
> file '/path/to/file3.wav'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If your .wav files don't contain sepcial characters like spaces, you can do :

```
files=(1.wav 2.wav ...)

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 ${files[@]/#/-i } -c copy output.wav
```